# Port priority on a TP-Link TD-W8951ND router

Tags: port, xbox360, priority

I have a TP-Link TD-W8951ND ADSL Router connected to an Xbox 360 console and PC with an Ethernet port. I want to set priority to the ports so that if the Xbox 360 is using the Internet, the PC connection speed will reduce.

With a little searching on Google I found out that I should use QoS settings to do this but my router's settings are confusing. I would really appreciate if anyone explains these settings for me.

[image]

Comment: thanks but i know it's in the QoS tab (Look at pic) but i don't understand the settings (like Mask or Protocol ID or ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QoS is a method of providing better service for selected network traffic types.  You need to know the IP address (or MAC address) of the Xbox.

If you do not know what Mask or Protocol IDs are, then this short text box will not be able to help you with all that.

What you would be doing is adding the MAC Address (as the Source) and telling it that its' traffic is HIGHER than other traffic.

Some of these options are enabled after others are selected, so I really can't walk you thought what you should type here as I do not have that same type of router.  The best you can do is search for some QoS examples from your router and play with the settings.  If learning was easy, it would be fun.